# GCE 上の Postfix への SMTP リクエスト

Tags: linux, google-cloud, postfix, google-compute-engine

初歩的な質問で失礼します。

GCE上にインスタンスを作成し、postfixをインストールおよび設定をし、sendmailコマンドでSnedgridを経由しての送信には成功しました。

postfixはリレーサーバとして利用したくインストールしており、いざWebアプリケーションからSMTPリクエストでGCEインスタンスの外部IPアドレス宛に送ってもうまく受信しません。

受信の設定(main.cf)として、mynetworksにWebアプリケーション側のIPアドレスを入力しています。また、inet_interfaces = allもしています。

そのほかにも設定が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: 「うまく受信しません」では何が起こっているのほとんどわかりませんので、回答する側は「電源コードはコンセントに挿さっていますか?」レベルの確認からしなくてはなりません。なにがどうした結果、何が起こっているのかを自分なりに調べて記載しましょう。例: Web アプリケーションからの SMTP の会話内容あるいはメール機能はどのような診断内容(ログ)を示しているか、そのときの Postfix 側のログの有無とログがあるならその内容、など。

Comment: エラーが起きていると思われるので、まずは`sudo apt bsd-mailx`でmailコマンドをインストールし、`mail <メールアドレス>`でメールが送信されるか確認してみてください。もし、メールが送信されていないようでしたら、`postqueue -p`などで、postfixのキューにメールがエラーで残っていないか確認してみてください。また、キューにメールが残っていなくても、受信側にスパムフィルタなどが入っていると、スパム判定されることもあるので、それも確認してみてください。なお、mailコマンドの使い方などは癖があるので、あらかじめ検索して確認してください。